# How do I sum up digits together within an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

Could anyone help me please.

I have created a function and within it I have an array containing string representations of integers.

```
var a = ['11', '22', '33' ,'44'];
```

What I am trying to do is to get a sum of individual digits in each element of the array. For example, the element containing `'11'` would give me `2` (1 + 1), `'22'` would give me `4` (2 + 2), and so on...  So I should get `[2,4,6,8]` as the final output. How can I do this.

Thank you,

Comment: What do you mean "a sum of digits"? It looks like you're multiplying them all by 2.

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm guessing he meant the output is [2,4,6,8], thats gotta be it right?

Comment: Yup, that is what he meant, I have edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant [2,4,6,8] as the output, which would be the sum of the digits of each **element** in the array you provided:

[JsBin Example](https://jsbin.com/pekudow/2/edit?js,console)

```
var a = ['11', '22', '33' ,'44'];

var b = a.map(function(num) {
  return num.split('').map(Number).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
}); 

// b = [2,4,6,8]
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, I have meant 2,4,6,8. Thank you.

Comment: np, I edited the question, so it should be fine now, hopefully some of the downvoters come back and un-dowvote you now

Answer (score 2):

`map` over the array, split each element, convert it to a number then add them, and return the final array.

```
function thing(arr) {
  return arr.map(function (el) {
    return el.split('').map(Number).reduce(function (p, c) {
      return p + c;
    });
  });
}

thing(arr) // [ 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
```

Or something more DRY with ES6:

```
const add = (a, b) => a + b;

function sumElements(arr) {
  return arr.map(el => [...el].map(Number).reduce(add));
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8jf8z73L/)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using mathematics:

```js
var a = ['11', '22', '33' ,'44'];
var res = a.map(Number).map(function(digit) {
   var result = 0;
   while(digit) {
      result += digit % 10;
      digit = Math.floor(digit/10);
   }
   return result;
});

document.write(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner with `ES6`

```
var a = ['11', '22', '33', '44'];

var result = a.map(e => e.split('').reduce((p, c) => +p + +c))

console.log(result); //[ 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work on all Browsers:

```
function wack(a){
  var r = [];
  for(var i=0,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
    var s = a[i].split(''), t = 0;
    for(var n=0,c=s.length; n<c; n++){
      t += +s[n];
    }
    r.push(t);
  }
  return r;
}
var test = ['11', '22', '33', '44', '111'];
console.log(wack(test));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you are asking, but I'll give it a go.

```
var a = [11,22,33,44];
var b = [];
for(i in a){
    b.push(a[i]*2);
}
//b == [22,44,66,88]
```

Your array is strings so you might want to wrap `a[i]` in the `Number()` function.